# Poor image quality when render-to-texture compared to render-to-screen

Tags: glsl, render-to-texture, webgl2, image-quality

To implement some post processing effects, I want to render the scene into a texture instead of directly render to the screen. For testing purposes I have drawn this texture over a simple quad that spans the whole screen. But the image quality is disappointing:

Render Scene To Screen

[image: Render Scene To Screen]

VS

Render Scene To Texture

[image: Render Scene To Texture]

I really do not know, why this is happening. The canvas size fits to the drawing buffer size. Also, when resizing the screen I create a completely new texture, frame & render buffer. Is my framebuffer setup incorrect? Or it is a WebGL limitation? I'm using Google Chrome & WebGL2.

```
function resize() {

  if (tex) { tex.delete(); }
  if (fb) { gl.deleteFramebuffer(fb); }
  if (rb) { gl.deleteRenderbuffer(rb); }

  fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

  tex = new Texture2D(null, {
    internalFormat: gl.RGB,
    width: gl.drawingBufferWidth,
    height: gl.drawingBufferHeight,
    minFilter: gl.LINEAR,
    magFilger: gl.LINEAR
  });

  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex.id, 0);



  rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
  gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
  gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH24_STENCIL8, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}

run() {
  gl.resize();
  gl.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  resize();

  gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

  gl.loop(() => {
    if (!ctx.scene || !ctx.car || !ctx.wheels) return;

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderScene();

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    screenShader.use();
    screen.bind();
    screenShader.screenMap = tex.active(0);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, screen.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  });
}
```

Comment: try turning off antiiasing on the canvas and see if the canvas quality drops to the texture quality. `gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2", { antialias: false })`

Comment: Are you sure your texture has the same resolution as your screen? I do not code in WEBGL but in GL there are limits on texture size and some implementations has it lower than screen resolutions... The image looks like resized does the texture size match exactly your view size (you know windows has borders too so window size is not the same as view size)?  The same goes for texture coordinates used did you use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` ? or adjusted your texture coordinates by `0.5` texel instead?

Comment: screen limits and textures limits are the same and there is no need to adjust by half a pixel

Comment: @gman Yes, you are right. with turned off antialias, the quality drops to the same texture quality...so does it mean, there is nothing i can do? Sizing the texture to the double screen width & height results in a good render result, but the performance suffers too much. Do you have an idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gman's hint it was possible to find the cause: In WebGL it is not possible to antialias a framebuffer. I was able to optimize the image quality with multisampled renderbuffers as described [here](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/webgl-2-new-features/).